# Beginner Python Objective Specific Explanation

Tags: python

```
A = [ [1, 1, 2], [2, 2, 3], [3, 3, 4] ]

x = 0
for i in range(2):
    x = x + A[i][i]
    print(x)
print(x)
```

The answer/output is:

```
1,3,3
```

How does that happen? Explain **everything** in detail

Comment: just explain everything in detail

Comment: That's to broad. What @ScottBoston is asking is: is there a specific part of the code you don't understand? The list creation? The for loop? The function calls? What? Simply saying "just explain everything in detail" is simply to broad.

Comment: By the way, the output is not `1,3,3`.  The output consists of the three numbers each printed on a separate line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you say

```
A = [ [1, 1, 2], [2, 2, 3], [3, 3, 4] ]
```

A is a list of lists. So,

> A[0] gives you [1,2,3] 
>   A[1] gives you [2,2,3]

A[0][0] is nothing but the 0th index of [1,2,3] which is 1.

and similarly, A[1][1] is the 1st index is [2,2,3] which is 2(the 2nd 2)

Now going back the program,

range(2) returns a list from 0 to 2, not including 2, so thats

```
[0,1]
```

so your looping through your program twice with i value being 0 and 1.

For the first line in the loop,

```
x = x + A[i][i]
```

becomes

```
x = 0 + A[0][0]
```

which is

```
x = 0 + 1
```

That explains your first print.

When you enter the loop again, you get this :

x = 1 + A[1][1] (because i is 1 and x was set to 1 in the previous loop.

which evaluates to

```
x = 1 + 2
```

Now the value of x is 3 and that explains your 2nd print statement.

The print outside the loop prints the current value of x, which is 3 and 
thats why you get

```
1,3,3
```

Answer (score -1):

A is a list of 3 elements, each has an index number, beginning with zero (0,1,2). Each element of the list is also a list.

The syntax `A[i]` returns the i-th value of the list. e.g. `A[0] = [1, 1, 2]`. The syntax A[i][i] returns the i-th value of the i-th list. `A[2][2] = 4`

1. `range(2)` evaluates to 0,1
2. The value of `i` is set to 0 for the first run of the `for` loop
3. `A[0][0]` evaluates to the first element of the first list (1). This is added to `x` to give `x` the value 1, which is printed
4. The second loop picks up `A[1][1]`, the second element of the second list (2). This is added to the value of `x`, which was 1. The new value of `x` is now printed (1 + 2 = 3).
5. The loop is finished and the value of `x` is unchanged and is printed again (3)